# Redirect current user to their most recent custom post

Tags: users, redirect

Is there a way that, if a user tries to access a particular page, they are redirected to their most recent post (In a custom post type)?

Or, if the user has no posts, redirect them to the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the permalink of a users most recent post (of custom post type) perform the following query:

```
$latest = get_posts(array(
        'author' => $current_user->ID,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
        'order' => 'desc',
        'numberposts' => 1,
    ));
    if( $latest ) {
      $url = get_permalink($latest[0]->ID);
    } else {
      // No posts
    }
```

For the redirect part take a look at the function [wp_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect).